# Improving Mancala Game

Tags: object-oriented, design-patterns, scala

https://www.mastersofgames.com/rules/mancala-rules.htm

I am trying to create a working Mancala Game in scala, Currently, I have 3 classes, `Board`, `Mancala` and `Player`.

Here is a copy of my `Board` class:

```
/**
 * The board of an ongoing game of mancala
 * @param player1: The number of seeds in each of lower player's pods (left to right)
 * @param bank1: The number of seeds in the lower player's bank
 * @param player2: The number of seeds in each of upper player's pods (left to right, from that player's perspective)
 * @param bank2: The number of seeds in the upper player's bank
 * @return a new board after the move takes place
 */
class Board(val player1: Seq[Int], val bank1: Int, val player2: Seq[Int], val bank2: Int) {

  /** Create a new board from a player taking a turn */
  def move(player: Int, position: Int): Board = {
    if (player != 1 && player != 2) throw new IllegalArgumentException
    if (position < 0 || position > 5) throw new IllegalArgumentException

    // Inner function for depositing seeds along a side
    def progress(seeds: Int, position: Int, side: Seq[Int]) = {
      val dist = math.min(seeds, 6 - position)
      val newSide = side.zipWithIndex.map {
        case (a, b) => if (b >= position && b < position + dist) a + 1 else a
      }
      (seeds - dist, newSide)
    }
    // Inner function for depositing a seed in the bank
    def depositInBank(seeds: Int, bank: Int): (Int, Int) = {
      if (seeds > 0) (seeds - 1, bank + 1) else (seeds, bank)
    }

    // Redistribute the pieces. Board movement positions are always counted
    // from the left
    val (startSide, oppSide) =
    if (player == 1) (player1.toArray, player2.reverse.toArray)
    else (player2.reverse.toArray, player1.toArray)
    val start = if (player == 1) position else 5 - position
    val playerBank = if (player == 1) bank1 else bank2
    if (startSide(start) == 0) throw new IllegalStateException
    val seeds = startSide(start)
    startSide(start) = 0
    val pos = start + 1

    // First side pass
    val (seedsFirstPass, playerPodsFirstPass) = progress(seeds, pos, startSide)
    val (seedsFirstPassAndBank, playerBankFirstPass) = depositInBank(seedsFirstPass, playerBank)

    // Move around the other side of the board
    val (seedsSecondPass, oppSideSecondPass) = progress(seedsFirstPassAndBank, 0, oppSide)

    // Skip the opponent's bank, but keep going if we can
    val (seedsThirdPass, playerPodsThirdPass) = progress(seedsSecondPass, 0, playerPodsFirstPass)

    // Stop by the bank
    val (seedsThirdsPassAndBank, playerBankSecondPass) = depositInBank(seedsThirdPass, playerBankFirstPass)

    // Just to be safe
    val (seedsFourthPass, oppSideFourthPass) = progress(seedsThirdsPassAndBank, 0, oppSideSecondPass)

    // Make our assumption explicit
    assert(seedsFourthPass == 0, "Still seeds after fourth pass, did not account for that")

    // Construct the new board
    if (player == 1)
      new Board(playerPodsThirdPass.toVector, playerBankSecondPass, oppSideFourthPass.reverse.toVector, bank2)
    else
      new Board(oppSideFourthPass.toVector, bank1, playerPodsThirdPass.reverse.toVector, playerBankSecondPass)
  }

  /** Capture pieces from a mancala game
   *
   * Pieces from the capturing pod and the opposite pod (same position, other player) are all emptied and moved
   * to the capturing player's bank.
   *
   * @param player the side (1 or 2) doing the capturing
   * @param pos the position doing the capturing
   * @return a new mancala board after the capture
   */
  def capture(player: Int, pos: Int): Board = {
    assert(player1(pos) != 0 && player2(pos) != 0)
    val (newBank1, newBank2) =
      if (player == 1)
        (bank1 + player1(pos) + player2(pos), bank2)
      else
        (bank1, bank2 + player1(pos) + player2(pos))
    new Board(player1.updated(pos, 0), newBank1, player2.updated(pos, 0), newBank2)
  }

  /** Calculate the last pod that will be visited by a move
   *
   * @param player the number (1, 2) of the player making the move
   * @param pos the index of the move about to be made (always counting from the left)
   * @return a tuple (player, pos) that represents the players side and position the last seed will be deposited in.
   *         A position of 6 represents a player's bank.
   */
  def lastPosAfterMove(player: Int, pos: Int): (Int, Int) = {
    val seeds = (if (player == 1) player1 else player2)(pos)
    val distToBank = if (player == 1) 6 - pos else pos + 1

    // Could use a better approach
    if (player == 1)
      if (seeds < distToBank) (1, pos + seeds)
      else if (seeds == distToBank) (1, 6)
      else if (seeds <= distToBank + 6) (2, 6 - (seeds - distToBank))
      else if (seeds <= distToBank + 12) (1, seeds - distToBank - 7)
      else if (seeds == distToBank + 13) (1, 6)
      else if (seeds <= distToBank + 19) (2, 19 - (seeds - distToBank))
      else { assert(false); (0, 0) }
    else
      if (seeds < distToBank) (2, pos - seeds)
      else if (seeds == distToBank) (2, 6)
      else if (seeds <= distToBank + 6) (1, seeds - distToBank - 1)
      else if (seeds <= distToBank + 12) (2, 12 - (seeds - distToBank))
      else if (seeds == distToBank + 13) (2, 6)
      else if (seeds <= distToBank + 19) (1, seeds - distToBank - 14)
      else { assert(false); (0, 0) }
  }

  override def toString = {
    val p2 = player2.foldLeft("")((a, b) => a + StringContext("  ", "  ").f(b)).trim
    val p1 = player1.foldLeft("")((a, b) => a + StringContext("  ", "  ").f(b)).trim
    val layer = "-" * 32
    val space = " " * 28
    f"""${layer + " "}\n   $p2 \n$bank2 ${space} $bank1\n   $p1\n${layer}"""
  }
}

/**
 * Board companion object. Used as a factory to create a starting board easily
 */
object Board {
  /** Create an initial board */
  def apply() = {
    val boardSide = Seq(4,4,4,4,4,4)
    new Board(boardSide, 0, boardSide, 0)
  }
}
```

I am trying to improve the `lastPosAfterMove()` and the `move()` functions, to make them more compact and understandable for others and use a better approach.

**-----------------------------------------------QUESTION EDIT-------------------------------------------------**

These are the other two classes
Player Class

```
import scala.io.StdIn

/**
 * A player in the Mancala game
 */

trait Player {
  /**
   * Get a player's move.
   * @param curBoard the current game configuration
   * @param currPlayer the current player
   * @return the player's choice
   */
  def getMove(curBoard: Board, currPlayer: Int): Int
}

/**
 * A human player.
 */
class HumanPlayer extends Player {
  /**
   * Get a player's move from StdIn.
   * @param curBoard the current game configuration
   * @param currPlayer the current player
   * @return the player's choice
   */
  def getMove(curBoard: Board, currPlayer: Int): Int = {
    var input: Int = StdIn.readChar - 'a'

    val helpMessage = "-------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"+
      "The board is represented by two lines, the upper line for the opponent\n"+
      "and the lower line for the current player. The number of pebbles is\n"+
      "shown for each pot, and the mancalas are given at the appropriate end\n"+
      "of each line. For the current player, pots are numbered left-to-right\n"+
      "from 1--6, followed by the player’s mancala. The opponent’s pots\n"+
      "(and mancala) are in reverse on the line before the player’s.\n"+
      "mancala   6 5 4 3 2 1\n"+
      "        0 4 4 4 4 4 4   <--- opponent\n"+
      "          4 4 4 4 4 4 0 <--- current player\n"+
      "          1 2 3 4 5 6 mancala\n"+
      "Player ’A’ moves first, and the player must enter their letter and pot\n"+
      "number because occasionally one player may get multiple moves.\n"+
      "Enter ’Q’ to quit.\n"+
      "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"

    while (input < 0 || input > 5) {
      if(input == 7 || input == -25){
        println(helpMessage)
      }
      else{
        println("!!!Invalid move: please enter player letter and pot number.")
      }
      input = StdIn.readChar - 'a'
    }
    input
  }
}
```

Mancala class

````
/** 
 * A State of a Mancala.
 * @param board -  game board
 * @param player - current player
 */
class Mancala(val board: Board, val player: Int) {
  
  /** 
   * Plays a turn
   */
  def playTurn(location: Int): Mancala = {

    val (side, position) = this.board.lastPosAfterMove(player, location)
    val updatedBoard = this.board.move(player, location)
    val nextTurn = if (location == 6) {
      player
    } else if (player == 1) {
      2
    } else{
      1
    }
    val playerSides = playerIdentifier()
    val finalBoard =
      if (side == player && playerSides._1(position) == 1 && position != 6 && playerSides._2(position) != 0){
        updatedBoard.capture(player, position)
      } else {
        updatedBoard
      }

    new Mancala(finalBoard, nextTurn)
  }

  def playerIdentifier(): (Seq[Int],Seq[Int]) = {
    if (this.player != 1) {
      (this.board.player2, this.board.player1)
    } else {
      (this.board.player1, this.board.player2)
    }
  }

  /**
   * Determines if a game is complete 
   */
  def isOver(): Boolean = {
    if(board.player1.forall(i => i == 0)){
      true
    } else if(board.player2.forall(i => i == 0)){
      true
    } else {
      false
    }
  }

  /**
   * Calculates the score after game is over.
   */
  def scoreCalculator(): (Int, Int) = {
    (this.board.player1.sum + this.board.bank1, this.board.player2.sum + this.board.bank2)
  }
}

object Manscala {

  def getPlayers: (Player, Player) = {
    (new HumanPlayer, new HumanPlayer)
  }

  def apply() = new Mancala(Board(), 1)

  /**
   * Helps in printing the board values. 
   */
  def printHelper() = {
    println("   a    b    c    d    e    f")
  }
  
  /** 
   * Driver of the program.
   */
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {

    println("\nWelcome to Mancala. Enter ’H’ for help, ’Q’ for quit.\n")

    var g = Manscala()

    val (player1, player2) = getPlayers

    while (!g.isOver()) {
      // Print the options on the side of the current player
      if (g.player == 1) {
        println(g.board)
        printHelper()
      } else {
        printHelper()
        println(g.board)
      }
      if (g.player == 1) {
        print("\nPlayer A's turn: \n")
      } else {
        print("\nPlayer B's turn: \n")
      }

      val pos: Int =  if (g.player == 1){
        player1.getMove(g.board, 1)
      } else {
        player2.getMove(g.board, 2)
      }
      g = g.playTurn(pos)
    }

    println(g.board)

    val scores = g.scoreCalculator()

    println("Player A: " + scores._1 + "Player B: " + scores._2)

    if (scores._1 > scores._2) {
      println("Player A is the winner!")
    } else {
      println("Player B is the winner!")
    }
  }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Without having seen the other classes, this one looks pretty good so
far.

- The comments are useful.  That's fantastic!
- `val space = " " * 28` lovely.
- Naming of variables is good and consistent.  I usually argue for
  spelled out variable names (`position`, etc.), but it's not that bad
  here.

A few things though that I'd consider:

- `move` is very long.  You've already made helper functions, so I'd
  move them up and make them private.
- The `IllegalArgumentException`s could use a descriptive message each,
  like
  `throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"invalid player value $player")`.
  Better yet, avoiding the situation by construction (see below).
- The indentation between `val (startSide, oppSide) =` and
  `val pos = start + 1` is odd, I'd at least give it a few more blank
  lines to make it more obvious what's happening.  Also move the checks
  closer to where the variables are set up
  (`if (startSide(start) == 0 ...` should probably come after
  `val start =`) to keep related things together.
- Consider naming arguments, although some IDEs will show them anyway.
- "Just to be safe" means what exactly?
- Are all the `toVector` and `toArray` calls necessary?  I'd have
  thought that no conversion for the `Seq`s should be necessary at all
  here?  Maybe a different type than `Seq` should be used here if random
  access is required anyway?
- If there are only two players, consider not making that implicit with
  using 1 and 2, but using an enumeration so that you *can't* get into a
  state where a `player` variable might be something unexpected.  Same
  actually goes for `position`, consider making it a case class to
  clearly distinguish between special values of positions (like 6 here).
- "Could use a better approach", that's true, it's a bit repetitive, but
  on the other hand, it's clear what's happening, maybe don't actually
  do anything about it.  The `assert(false); {0, 0)` should be an
  `IllegalStateException` or something along those lines if you can't
  rule out the illegal state via some other means (`assert(false)`
  doesn't tell the reader anything).  Continuing with an invalid state
  is very bad generally and that's where exceptions can be easily used
  to avoid that.
- `toString` can omit the `{}` parts for a simple variable.
- My IDE also suggests giving each public member a type declaration, I
  tend to agree with that.  In this case `progress` should also have a
  type declared, it helps with reading the whole thing.
- There are some magic constants in the code, of course 0, though I'd
  say that doesn't count, but 6 definitely does.  Consider making that a
  constant and use it in the appropriate places, even for 5
  (`Board.SIZE - 1` or some such).  It'll never change, yes, but it
  makes the intent more clear to the reader.  I don't understand the
  logic enough to apply this suggestion to `lastPosAfterMove`, but it
  applies there too, for 7, 12, 13, 19, etc., presumably those are
  derived from the board size.
- I'd inline `pos`.
- Not quite sure without running it what the `foldLeft` sequence does,
  but exactly for that reason I'd make it a helper function and reuse it
  once.

Some style ideas that I'm super sure with:

- Ranges could be used, like `!(0 until 6).contains(position)` to check
  for validity.  It looks clearer to me, but YMMV.

---

I hope I didn't mix anything up, that said, this is how I'd probably do
the things outlined above:

```
/**
 * The board of an ongoing game of mancala
 *
 * @param player1 : The number of seeds in each of lower player's pods (left to right)
 * @param bank1   : The number of seeds in the lower player's bank
 * @param player2 : The number of seeds in each of upper player's pods (left to right, from that player's perspective)
 * @param bank2   : The number of seeds in the upper player's bank
 * @return a new board after the move takes place
 */
class Board(val player1: IndexedSeq[Int], val bank1: Int, val player2: IndexedSeq[Int], val bank2: Int) {

  import Board._

  object Player extends Enumeration {
    type Player = Value
    val First, Second = Value
  }

  import Player._

  // Depositing seeds along a side
  private def progress(seeds: Int, position: Int, side: IndexedSeq[Int]): (Int, IndexedSeq[Int]) = {
    val dist = math.min(seeds, Size - position)
    val newSide = side.zipWithIndex.map {
      case (a, b) => if ((position until position + dist).contains(b)) a + 1 else a
    }
    (seeds - dist, newSide)
  }

  private def depositInBank(seeds: Int, bank: Int): (Int, Int) =
    if (seeds > 0) (seeds - 1, bank + 1) else (seeds, bank)

  /** Create a new board from a player taking a turn */
  def move(player: Player, position: Int): Board = {
    if (!(0 until Size).contains(position)) throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"invalid position value $position is out of bounds")

    // Redistribute the pieces. Board movement positions are always counted
    // from the left
    val (startSide, oppSide) =
    if (player == First) (player1.toArray, player2.reverse.toArray)
    else (player2.reverse.toArray, player1.toArray)

    val start = if (player == First) position else Size - 1 - position
    if (startSide(start) == 0) throw new IllegalStateException(s"invalid value for $start ...")

    val playerBank = if (player == First) bank1 else bank2

    val seeds = startSide(start)
    startSide(start) = 0

    // First side pass
    val (seedsFirstPass, playerPodsFirstPass) = progress(seeds, position = start + 1, startSide)
    val (seedsFirstPassAndBank, playerBankFirstPass) = depositInBank(seedsFirstPass, playerBank)

    // Move around the other side of the board
    val (seedsSecondPass, oppSideSecondPass) = progress(seedsFirstPassAndBank, position = 0, oppSide)

    // Skip the opponent's bank, but keep going if we can
    val (seedsThirdPass, playerPodsThirdPass) = progress(seedsSecondPass, position = 0, playerPodsFirstPass)

    // Stop by the bank
    val (seedsThirdsPassAndBank, playerBankSecondPass) = depositInBank(seedsThirdPass, playerBankFirstPass)

    // Just to be safe
    val (seedsFourthPass, oppSideFourthPass) = progress(seedsThirdsPassAndBank, position = 0, oppSideSecondPass)

    // Make our assumption explicit
    assert(seedsFourthPass == 0, "Still seeds after fourth pass, did not account for that")

    // Construct the new board
    if (player == First)
      new Board(playerPodsThirdPass, playerBankSecondPass, oppSideFourthPass.reverse, bank2)
    else
      new Board(oppSideFourthPass, bank1, playerPodsThirdPass.reverse, playerBankSecondPass)
  }

  /** Capture pieces from a mancala game
   *
   * Pieces from the capturing pod and the opposite pod (same position, other player) are all emptied and moved
   * to the capturing player's bank.
   *
   * @param player the side doing the capturing
   * @param pos    the position doing the capturing
   * @return a new mancala board after the capture
   */
  def capture(player: Player, pos: Int): Board = {
    assert(player1(pos) != 0 && player2(pos) != 0)
    val toAdd = player1(pos) + player2(pos)
    val (newBank1, newBank2) =
      if (player == First)
        (bank1 + toAdd, bank2)
      else
        (bank1, bank2 + toAdd)
    new Board(player1.updated(pos, 0), newBank1, player2.updated(pos, 0), newBank2)
  }

  /** Calculate the last pod that will be visited by a move
   *
   * @param player the player making the move
   * @param pos    the index of the move about to be made (always counting from the left)
   * @return a tuple (player, pos) that represents the player and position the last seed will be deposited in.
   *         A position of 6 represents a player's bank.
   */
  def lastPosAfterMove(player: Player, pos: Int): (Player, Int) = {
    val seeds = (if (player == First) player1 else player2) (pos)
    val distToBank = if (player == First) Size - pos else pos + 1

    if (player == First)
      if (seeds < distToBank) (First, pos + seeds)
      else if (seeds == distToBank) (First, Size)
      else if (seeds <= distToBank + Size) (Second, Size - (seeds - distToBank))
      else if (seeds <= distToBank + 12) (First, seeds - distToBank - 7)
      else if (seeds == distToBank + 13) (First, Size)
      else if (seeds <= distToBank + 19) (Second, 19 - (seeds - distToBank))
      else throw new IllegalStateException(s"value for seeds $seeds out of bounds")
    else
      if (seeds < distToBank) (Second, pos - seeds)
      else if (seeds == distToBank) (Second, Size)
      else if (seeds <= distToBank + Size) (First, seeds - distToBank - 1)
      else if (seeds <= distToBank + 12) (Second, 12 - (seeds - distToBank))
      else if (seeds == distToBank + 13) (Second, Size)
      else if (seeds <= distToBank + 19) (First, seeds - distToBank - 14)
      else throw new IllegalStateException(s"value for seeds $seeds out of bounds")
  }

  private def foo(x: IndexedSeq[Int]): String =
    x.foldLeft("")((a, b) => a + StringContext("  ", "  ").f(b)).trim

  override def toString: String = {
    val layer = "-" * 32
    val space = " " * 30
    f"""$layer\n   ${foo(player2)}\n$bank2$space$bank1\n   ${foo(player1)}\n$layer"""
  }
}

/**
 * Board companion object. Used as a factory to create a starting board easily
 */
object Board {
  val Size = 6

  /** Create an initial board */
  def apply(): Board = {
    val boardSide = List.fill(Size)(4).toVector
    new Board(boardSide, bank1 = 0, boardSide, bank2 = 0)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove the passes and use something more resourceful and efficient @ferada

Comment: Hello @ferada I have updated the question with the other two classes, your last review discarded the possibility of introducing a computer player which was my next addition. So if you could suggest something in that regards it would be great